# Windows 10 GPU selection is ignored - how to force app to use integrated GPU?

Tags: windows, windows-10, graphics-card, gpu, nvidia-graphics-card

I have two graphic card. One is integrated Intel UHD, the second is Nvidia 1650 ti. I have several programs constantly running on my dedicated GPU (Nvidia), while I'd rather prefer to have them on integrated card. I have Windows 10 21H1, so the Nvidia control panel is ignored, I have to set it in system settings like here:
[image: settings]

As you can see, I set an application to "Power saving" by using integrated GPU (intel UHD). This is Samsung Magician app, to be more specified. However, as you can see belowe, this option is ignored, and it still runs on Nvidia:

[image: nvidia activity]

How to prevent the system from ignoring my selection? In nvidia control panel it worked fine, but now, I'm forced to use Windows settings, which seems to not work properly.

Comment: The Nvidia Control Panel absolutely preferences shouldn’t be ignored even if you are running 21H1

Comment: Can you elaborate? I don't see any difference in the matter of GPU selection in control panel. There is even and disclaimer that I should use system settings instead, but as I mentioned earlier, this doesn't work.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Partially, but not the way you probably expect. I updated to Windows 11, and now it works much better. Still sometimes it runs app on dedicated GPU while it should be on integrated, but it is like an app from time to time, vs lots of apps all the time in Win10.